# Composer, Git And Deployment Workflow

Tags: silverstripe

This is more of a general question regarding Git, but I'm applying it towards SS so thought I'd ask here. I'm a designer learning Git.

I'm looking for best way to work dev environment and live server. My setup now is to use composer and GitHub for Mac locally to work on projects on my Mac. I then use [Beam](https://github.com/heyday/beam) to deploy to live server.

The issue I'm having is I can't commit SS modules to my repo for the project. Using GitHub for Mac, and it says 'failed to add *module-name* to index'. I'm still not clear on why this is happening. Because they're submodules with git?

So what I do is use Beam to deploy things like theme, custom code to live server, then from live server I login and run composer to install and update modules. It would be ideal if I could just push everything from my dev server live, and not have to login and run composer commands on live server. This would also help for client sites that don't have composer installed on crappy shared hosting.

So is there a workaround or better method for deploying to live servers I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2):

I manage modules with [composer](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/installation/composer) and add the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` to your git repo and all module directories to `.gitignore`. With composer you can easily update the framework and modules later on.

You can automate some deployment, either using something like [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) or using [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Capistrano works from your side, it logs in on the live server, pulls, and does some jobs for you. There are some capistrano receipes for SilverStripe out in the wild. It has some advantages (e.g. on dir for each release, easy rollback, backup of DB for each release etc...), but for me it felt a bit overkill for very simple websites i want to deploy real a hotfix real quickly.

With git hooks you still have to login on the live server, go to your webroot and run `git pull`. Then git will pull your lastest changes from the repo and do some jobs for you. I have this [git post-merge hook for SilverStripe](https://gist.github.com/wernerkrauss/33dcb098c05ed063be22) running (just copy the script to `.git/hooks/post-merge` on the live server):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "running git post receive hook..."
DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

if [ -e "$DIR/composer.json" ]; then
if [ -d "$DIR/vendor" ]; then
composer.phar install
else
composer.phar update
fi
fi

echo "running dev/build"
sudo -u www-data php $DIR/framework/cli-script.php dev/build flush=1
```

It runs a `composer install` or `composer update` and a `dev/build` for me automatically.

One more tip: Don't put your database credentials or dev/test/live mode in your git repo. Use [_ss_environment.php](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/environment-management) instead. One for each machine.

Comment: There was also a talk about SilverStripe deployment at the 1st Silverstripe Europe Conference in Linz this year: http://www.anselm.dk/static/talks/silverstripe-europe-meetup-2014/deployment.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot @wmk. There is some great info for me to go through. I'm still wondering about shared hosting where I don't have ssh/git/composer on live servers. Beam is like capistrano it seems and what I have been using. I manage SS with composer for modules, but because they are downloaded with a .git directory, I can't commit them to my repo for the project, and thus I can't use beam to deploy to live server as they aren't checked in. Is there a way to add modules to my repo so I can deploy to live server? This is only to workaround shared hosting where I don't have access to composer.

Comment: Depends on your IDE. With PHPStorm e.g. (others surely, too) you can also deploy via ftp through the IDE. As you have to install the whole project locally for coding you can upload all needed files and you're done. I use it for some very simple sites, though i absolutely prefer ssh.
When deploying via ftp you'll have to run `dev/build` manually.
And afaik capistrano can also deploy via ftp, so it runs composer etc. locally and puts it on the server.

Comment: Ya I was thinking for small shared hosting sites, I'd just upload via FTP but Beam does support ftp as well as ssh. The issue I'm having is if I use composer to manage SS in dev server, I can't check SS modules into my own repo for the project because the module has its own .git folder in the directory. Is there a way around this? in GitHub for Mac https://www.dropbox.com/s/5m4mcz0n7uplqa9/Screenshot%202014-12-06%2008.36.01.png?dl=0 If I could check everything into my own repo, I can use Beam to deploy via FTP for shared hosting, & not have to run composer on live server. Hack workaround

Comment: Capistrano supports ftp deployment.

Comment: right as does Beam like I mentioned. But with Capistrano, don't you have to check in commits to Git and then it uses that to decided which files are new/modified and need to be uploaded? And since I can't commit modules to my repo as they have a .git folder in them, with Beam, it doesn't know to upload them and I have to resort to manually FTPing them myself, or use composer on the server side. The latter is fine, except when I don't have access on shared hosting. Still learning it all so I'll take a further look I suppose and see best option for shared hosting workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything else but Git. They have these software and tools to make things easier but it gets too cluttered, confusing and too many things.

Layout: 
on a dev server install git and start the project

on a dev server, edit, add, delete and commit files to the repo

on the prod install `git pull` from git repo

when you develop, `git commit` to the repo from dev

when you want to publish, go to the live server and issue gut pull

this is how i've done it with cvs and svn. its the same idea with git. it works like a charm.

make sure you do **`ssh over http`**, its better.

this is just my opinion from personal experience; don't take it word for word. i'm sure others have done it differently.

Comment: bitbucket was a huge factor.

Comment: I disagree: You should manage dependencies (including modules) through Composer. Do not use Git submodules, check the code into your repository or manage the dependencies by hand. If you need something like Beam is more a matter of taste — this is optional, but Git and Composer are the current best practice

Comment: never use git submodules, they are a not a good solution to manage compared to composer